# SQL Server memory increase create issues with SSIS package

Tags: sql-server, ssis

We've been using maximum server memory of 22000 (MB) on the SQL server to run the SSIS packages via SQL agent job. Recently we increased the memory to 28000 (MB) and this cause the package to halt. The SQL job just sits on the server for hours doing nothing.

Why is this happening and how can we fix it?

Comment: What is your source? What is your destination? If either is a database, have you looked for blocking activity on them?

Comment: Good point. Is it the package or the database that is the hold up? That is the very first question that you need to find an answer for. Some package tasks use a lot of memory, some don't.

Comment: If your package is executed on the same machine, how much memory is available for the SSIS engine now? Is it enough? Check with performance counters.

Comment: I had this myself on a VM I was doing some testing on. Turned out to be a case of ballooning. Your SSIS package is probably just waiting for memory to execute. Check your wait types if you have an active SQL Server connection too. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179984.aspx

Comment: The source and the destination are SQL databases. The machine has total 32 GB of memory. I think the problem is that when I allocate 28 GB to SQL Server the SSIS has no enough memory to run. How do I find out how much memory does the SSIS need?

Answer (score 0):

It is always better to provide 10 to 20% memory for OS and allocate rest to SQL Server. If SSIS running on same server then provide around 70% only to SQL Server.

It all depends on how much we are running on SSIS as well.. Do you really have Memory bottleneck? Use below query to check that...

```
SELECT  
(physical_memory_in_use_kb/1024) AS Memory_usedby_Sqlserver_MB,  
(locked_page_allocations_kb/1024) AS Locked_pages_used_Sqlserver_MB,  
(total_virtual_address_space_kb/1024) AS Total_VAS_in_MB,  
process_physical_memory_low,  
process_virtual_memory_low  
FROM sys.dm_os_process_memory;
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there any options to control the memory usage on the SSIS side? For example modifying the DefaultBufferMaxRow or some other properties? When I run the package I see the C-drive filling up with DTS.tmp files.

Comment: We can provide enough memory/processing capabilities for dtexec.exe.. Some of SSIS performance counters we can track for performance tuning, but not sure for c-drive which is filiing up... Buffers in use,
Flat buffers in use

Comment: I have multiple SSIS packages running on the sql server throughout the day (can see the execution history reports), however if I set the OS perfmon counter for SSIS: Buffer memory, then it shows 0. What could be the reason?